# running a process in another namespace

Tags: namespace, network-namespaces

I would like to run a new process (for example an xterm) in another network namespace. This could be done like this:

```
sudo ip netns exec otherns sudo -u $USER xterm
```

This command looks a bit complicated and involves running a `sudo` which runs `ip` which runs `sudo` which runs the final `xterm`.

Is there a more direct way to run a process in a new namespace?

I was thinking of writing a own small (SUID or capability enabled) binary which switches namespace restores permissions and user and runs the command, but shouldn't there already be some standard tool doing exactly that?

This would allow me to simply call something like:

```
runns otherns xterm
```

Comment: Do you have a kernel 3.8 (necessary for user namespaces)? If so you shouldn't need sudo at all. The basic tool to create a namespace is `unshare`.

Comment: My kernel is 4.0.4. Namespaces are available and working. (In this case I am talking about network namespaces not user namespaces.) Both the `unshare` and the `setns` system call need the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability, hence "normal" users are not allowed to switch namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Would the `--setuid` option of [nsenter(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html) come to your rescue? Such as in:

```
sudo nsenter --net=/run/netns/otherns --setuid 1000 --setguid 1000 xterm
```